# UISearchController - Black Rectangle

Tags: swift, cocoa, navigation, tableview, ios11

I'm implementing a simple tableViewController with UISearchcontroller.

The problem is that every time that I press the search field then a black rectangle appear right after the keyboard shows up.

I also tried to use definesPresentationContext and searchBarStyle but it keep showing the rectangle. On the other hand, it looks like doesn't happen in the simulator since there is no keyboard.

Update: Below some photos.

ViewController:

```
class ListGlobalViewController: UITableViewController, StoryboardSceneBased, ViewModelBased {

  static var sceneStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "DataSelectorViewController", bundle: Bundle.main)

  // --------------------
  // MARK: - Properties
  // --------------------
  var viewModel: ListGlobalViewModel!
  private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()


  private let searchController: UISearchController = {
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
    return searchController
  }()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    configure(with: viewModel)

    navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
  }

  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
  }

  override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    self.searchController.isActive = false
  }
  override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
  }

  // --------------------
  // MARK: - Functions
  // --------------------
  func configure(with viewModel: ListGlobalViewModel) {
    self.tableView.delegate = nil
    self.tableView.dataSource = nil

    viewModel.outputs.listDataObservable.bind(to: self.tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "listGlobalCell", cellType: ListGlobalCell.self)) { (index, model, cell) in
       cell.model = model
    }.disposed(by: disposeBag)

    searchController.searchBar.rx.text.filterNil().throttle(1, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance).distinctUntilChanged().subscribe(viewModel.inputs.searchBarObservable).disposed(by: disposeBag)

  }
}
```

Navigation Default Values:

```
let controller = UINavigationController()
    controller.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    controller.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    controller.definesPresentationContext = true
    controller.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.bold(size: 24), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black ]

    if #available(iOS 11, *) {
      controller.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [ NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.bold(size: 33), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black ]
    }
    return controller
```

Pictures:
[image: Normal State]

Bugged
[image: Bugged state]

Answer (score 0):

Use `UITextField` instead if `UISearchBar`. You can give any design to uitextfield. UISearch bar has limited designable attributes. Also you can reach any search function with textfield.

Comment: Yes but that’s not a real solution. Thanks anyways

Comment: I think, this problem is about keyboard size. You can use this repo. https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Comment: I was already using IQKeyboard. Its enabled by default and I tried 
    IQKeyboardManager.shared().isEnabled = false (disabling) and the black rectangle is gone.